# Como ordenar o DATA da url do Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de ordenar os nomes do `data` dos estados em ordem crescente. Como faço isso?

```
function retornaEstados()
{
    var opcaoCadastro = "";
    $.ajax({
      url: urlBase + "estado",
      method: 'GET'
    }).success(function(retorno)
    {
      retorno.data.forEach(function(item)
      {
        opcaoCadastro = $("<option value=" + item.estado_id + ">" + item.nome + "</option>");
        $(".estadoendereco").append(opcaoCadastro);
      });
    }).error(function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que `data` é um `array`, você pode utilizar o método `sort()` do JavaScript:

```
retorno.data.sort(function(a, b){ return a.nome > b.nome; })
```

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Exemplo no JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s4o4nnbd/

Answer (score 0):

Se você está querendo organizar os `options` por ordem alfabética, considerando também os acentos, utilize este código após o *loop*:

```
$(".estadoendereco").html($(".estadoendereco option").sort(function (a,b){
        return (a.text).localeCompare(b.text);
    }));
```